# View usage of Photos app

Tags: photo-stream, photos.app

I'm wondering how you can view the size of each photo or video in the Photos app on an iPhone 4S. I have a lot of photos/videos and want to see how much space they are using. I go to Settings > General > Usage but don't see the Photos app listed under Storage. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

One way I know of, which would be tedious to use for all of your photos unfortunately, is to email a photo from the camera roll. When you hit `Send` on the email, you're offered choices of sending a compressed photo (Small, Medium, or Large), or the original size. Each of the choices lists what the resulting image file size would be, and this includes the original size.

Answer (score 0):

There is no convenient built-in solution but [LightLoupe](http://boinx.com/lightloupe/) from Boinx Software will let you browse a "thumbnail page" for your Saved Photos, or any Album in your Photo Library, and provide image (W x H in pixels) and file (bytes) size for any photo selected. You can also view a histogram and other data.

I'm certain there are other Photo Utility apps with similar functions.

Less than ideal but less labor intensive than the faux email export technique.

Comment: LightLoupe doesn't seem to be available for iPhone?

Comment: My mistake. It is an iPad only solution.